# Do create an EclipseLink EntityManager per method call or guard with a lock?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

should I create an EclipseLink EntityManager per method call, store in thread local or guard with a lock?

Obviously it's initially created from entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().

Which is best practise please?

With per method call I'm concerned with performance.

With thread local I'm concern about cache visibility between threads.

With guarding a single EntityManager with a lock I have the cost of a lock each time.

/I'm using JSE - so no EJBs, no injtection - just entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() in a multi-threaded JSE app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityManagers are not thread safe, and are designed to represent a unit of work.  Each method/thread should have its own unless participating in a larger transaction.  It is also better to close/clear them at logical points because they maintain a cache of managed entities that can grow large with long lived EntityManagers.  There are numerous posts on what the best way to go is outside and inside a container.

EclipseLink's EntityManager uses EclipseLink's native sessions and unitOfWork underneath, which will lazily fetch resources as required, and release them when done.  But they can be configured to operate differently.